# how to use button_to click event in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new in rails.I am wondering that how to use the click event in rails 4.1.
In menus_controller:

```
def index 
  @menus=Menu.where(:hotel_id=>@hotel.id).sorted     
  @cart = current_cart

if :MEAL
  @menus=Menu.where(:hotel_id=>params[:hotel_id],:item_type=>'Meal').sorted     
  @cart = current_cart    
end
```

in Menus/index:
    `<%=button_to("MEAL",{:controller=>'menus',:action=>'index',:hotel_id=>params[:hotel_id]}, class:'linkstyle ')%>`

After using the above code the page gets redirected to `Menus#create`,why this happened?
In index page i have this button and i want to stay in the same page after clicked this button which will call the if block in the index method in controller.

Comment: Should be `("MEAL", {:controller=>'menus',:action=>'index',:hotel_id=>params[:hotel_id]},`

Comment: `{:controller=>'menus',:action=>'index',:hotel_id=>params[:hotel_id]}` after using this still the page is redirected to `Menus#create`.And if block is not working also.

Comment: if you are in some controller then use only {:action=>'index',:hotel_id=>params[:hotel_id]}